# Converting variable tab limited file to new line entry

Tags: file, awk, sed

I have a huge file (over 1000 lines) in the following format

```
000005  chair   chair   chair   chair   chair
000007  car
000009  horse   person  person  person
000012  car
000016  bicycle
000017  person  horse
000019  cat cat
000020  car
```

I want to convert it into the following

```
000005  chair   
000005  chair   
000005  chair   
000005  chair   
000005  chair
000007  car
000009  horse   
000009  person  
000009  person  
000009  person
000012  car
000016  bicycle
000017  person  
000017  horse
000019  cat 
000019  cat
000020  car
```

Is there a way to do it via sed or awk or any other file scripting language without having to manually go through it and fix every line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}' file
000005 chair
000005 chair
000005 chair
000005 chair
000005 chair
000007 car
000009 horse
000009 person
000009 person
000009 person
000012 car
000016 bicycle
000017 person
000017 horse
000019 cat
000019 cat
000020 car
```

The above produces space-separated output.  If you want tab-separated output, then use:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1"\t"$i}' file
```

How it works:

- `for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)`

  This starts a loop over all fields, `i`, starting with the second and continuing to the last.
- `print $1"\t"$i`

  This prints the first field, followed by a tab, followed by the i-th field.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\
 /g
:cycle
s/^\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\(.*\)\(\n\) /\1\2\3\1 /
t cycle
s/^\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\n//' YourFile
```

- use   (space char) as space separator (your sample seems to show 2 or a tab)
- more for fun if you can use awk

Comment: Nice sed-fu.  Plus 1.